# Rust impl default trait with private fields

Tags: rust, default, private, public

I'm getting an error when I have this sort of setup:

default_test.rs:

```rust
mod default_mod;

use default_mod::Point;

fn main() {
    let _p1 = Point::new();
    let _p2: Point = Point {
        z: 1,
        ..Default::default()
    };
}
```

default_mod.rs:

```rust
pub struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    pub z: i32,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Point { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
    }
}

impl Default for Point {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Point { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
    }
}
```

which gives the compiler error:

```
default_test.rs:9:7
  |
9 |     ..Default::default()
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ field `x` is private

error[E0451]: field `y` of struct `default_mod::Point` is private
```

Short version - I have a struct with both public and private fields.  I would like to initialise this struct with default values, but sometimes override them.

I can't seem to fix this error, nor seen anything on the internet or the docs that even mentions errors like this.

It surprises me, because I'd think a common use-case would be to initialise a struct, and that some members of the struct would be private so you can hide implementation details behind and interface.

In my case the private field is a `Vec` as I have some logic that needs to go into adding or removing things from the vector, so I want to make it private to prevent anyone messing up the data structure.

What are my options here?

Comment: What about moving your public fields to a separated type: `pub struct Data { pub x: i32, pub y: i32}; pub struct Point { pub data: Data, z: i32 };` and then do a `fn new_with_data(data: Data)`? Your layout changes a bit, but it should kind of work.

Comment: I actually quite like this idea, I'll have a think about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It surprises me, because I'd think a common use-case would be to initialise a struct, and that some members of the struct would be private so you can hide implementation details behind and interface.

The problem is that the struct update syntax  doesn't do what you think it does. For example, [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax) shows the following code:

```
let user2 = User {
    email: String::from("another@example.com"),
    username: String::from("anotherusername567"),
    ..user1
};
```

The `..user1` syntax fills in the `User` fields we haven't explicitly specified, such as `active: user1.active, signin_count: user1.signin_count`. `..` may be followed by an arbitrary expression which returns the structure, which is where `Default::default()` comes into play, and means the same as `User::default()` because a `User` is expected. However, the desugaring remains unchanged and boils down to assigning individual fields, in neither case granting special access to private fields.

To get back to your example, this code:

```
let p = Point {
    z: 1,
    ..Default::default()
};
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
let p = {
    let _tmp = Point::default();
    Point {
        x: _tmp.x, // assigning private field
        y: _tmp.y, // assigning private field
        z: 1,
    }
};
```

and not for the expected:

```
// NOT what happens
let p = {
    let _tmp = Point::default();
    p.z = 1; // no private assignment
    _tmp
};
```

> What are my options here?

The most idiomatic option is to provide a [builder](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/ownership/builders.html) for `Point`. That is also somewhat bulky<sup>1</sup>, so if you're looking for a simple solution, you could also use `Point::default()` and set the `z` attribute manually. The struct update syntax is incompatible with structs with private fields and just not useful for your type.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Though there are crates like [derive_builder](https://crates.io/crates/derive_builder), [typed-builder](https://crates.io/crates/typed-builder) and [builder-pattern](https://crates.io/crates/builder-pattern) that take some of the drudgery away.

Answer (score 3):

> What are my options here?

A `new()` with parameters or a builder.

`..struct` is just a convenient way of doing functional updates, it doesn't bypass ACLs. Here since your struct has private fields, users *can not* manipulate it as a "bare" struct, they have to treat it as a largely opaque type.

Comment: I think the OP didn't expect `..struct` to bypass ACLs, but to start with`struct` and update the fields explicitly specified, which is the public `z` in the OP's case.

Comment: But that's not what they're doing, what they're doing is creating a new struct copying the old one while replacing one of the field's values.

Comment: Agreed, it's just that the OP's _interpretation_ of the struct-update syntax is different from its actual meaning. Since I remember experiencing similar confusion when I first encountered the interaction of struct-update syntax with private fields, I tried to cover it in my answer.